# How do you quickly renumber a numbered list in emacs after you re-order its elements?

Tags: emacs

Suppose you start with this list

```
1- tofu
2- vinegar
3- salt
4- ground beef
5- white sugar
```

And then you want white sugar to be number 3. You kill 5-White sugar, go right beneath 2-vinegar and yank it :

```
1- tofu
2- vinegar
5- white sugar
3- salt
4- ground beef
```

Now you have to re-order salt and ground beef (You're lucky the list isn't much long). How do you do this in the most effective manner ?

*EDIT* : without org-mode.

Comment: It's trivial if (a) you use [org mode](https://orgmode.org/)  (b) use "1." instead of "1-"

Comment: (1) Make your file "something.org" -- Emacs should go into org mode. (2) Use [plain lists](https://orgmode.org/guide/Plain-Lists.html#Plain-Lists). (3) C-c C-c after the shuffling

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using macros.

1. (re)set macro counter to 1 : `C-x C-k C-c` (defaults to 0)
2. Start recording a macro for the first line `C-x (`
3. insert macro counter : `C-x C-k C-i`
4. Go to the beginning of next line then end macro `C-x )`
5. Select other items then : `M-x apply-macro-to-region-lines`

The macro will be played on all remaining lines.

Comment: Even if you don't want org I think cua-mode's sub-mode — [column editing mode](https://vimeo.com/1168225) is cleaner than keyboard macros. (Yeah cua messes up C-c, C-x to the point of unusability. So I typically activate cua, do column editing and immediately deactivate )